# Apply :focus for a class name in html css

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have an input text box. On selecting the same, the highlighter(blue box around text box) appears. I need a single red line as border-bottom on input text box selection. Please see the code:

```css
input:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.myclass:focus {
  border-bottom: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

<form>
  First input box: <input class="myclass" type="text" name="firstname"><br> 
  Second input box: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

As I have multiple input textbox in my page and I want to apply style to only one textbox. So I can't use the input:focus code. How can I apply ':focus' to a particular class in css? Please help thanks in advance

Comment: `.myclass:focus ` doesn't work?

Comment: you need to style the [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) not focus, but not sure if you can only do one side - you probably want to cancel the outline and then use border-bottom with the :focus

Comment: nope I dont know why

Comment: border width give, like `border:1px soild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding outline:color and modifying border style. Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    input:focus {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .myclass:focus {        
  border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5px red;
    outline: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

    <form>
    First input box: <input class="myclass" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Second input box: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you Pete for the spark, mentioning that the highlighter is outline. And for all who answered.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this

```css
.myclass:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `border-bottom-color` instead  `border-bottom` to set **only** `color`(red)

Or use   `border-bottom:1px solid red`

```css
input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.myclass:focus {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

<form>
First input box: <input class="myclass" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Second input box: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are getting applied, just the semantics are wrong.
Use below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.myclass:focus {
    border-bottom: solid 2px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

<form>
First input box: <input class="myclass" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Second input box: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this code.
Nothing Else is needed. It will turn your button red upon Click.

.myclass:focus
{

```
 border:1px solid #FF0000;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the border size and type not only the color

look to the exemple bellow

```
.myclass:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```